Select word from sentence containing certain letters
I want to select a word (D) from a sentence (B) based on some word/text (A) I give.
I get output (C) using the following code:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1;B1));A1;"NA")




A (word/text)
B (sentence)
C    (output)
D   (wanted output)




apple
I have an applepie
apple
applepie


bear
this life is unbearable
bear
unbearable


hat
the mad hatter is wise
hat
hatter


ness
I met the loch-ness monster
ness
loch-ness



How do I display the entire word (e.g. applepie) in stead of just the letters I am looking for (e.g. apple) ?

Something like this would work:
=FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),IFERROR(SEARCH(A2,TEXTSPLIT(B2," ")),0))

Result:

It will spill multiple results (see row 6), you can TEXTJOIN if needed.

The complete code in case of textjoin and NA if the word does not appear is =TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;IFERROR(FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(B2;" ");IFERROR(SEARCH(A2;TEXTSPLIT(B2;" "));0));"NA"))
